# Setting up ssh on Debian to allow some users log in with ldap

Tags: ssh, ftp, ldap, sftp

I have a server in which users can't login via ssh but can upload files by sftp. This server has an ldap database of users and ssh and sftp are configured with the ldap, so none of the ldap users can't login via ssh but can upload files via sftp.

But now I want to do another thing: I want to allow one specified ldap user to log in via ssh.

Is that possible? Is there any chance of having this working?

I tried with AllowUsers in sshd_config but it seems not working.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about how your ssh server checks users against LDAP to decide whether to allow access? How did you originally prevent users from having normal ssh access?

Comment: Hi, Dan. To prevent users from having normal ssh access I use these directives: Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group ldapgroup
         ChrootDirectory /users/%u
         X11Forwarding no
         AllowTcpForwarding no
         ForceCommand internal-sftp
Match

Comment: AllowUsers in sshd_config, man sshd_config can help you